# Trying to factorise an equation to give results

Tags: math-mode

I would like to use factorisation to provide the results to the following code;

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$$
ax^2+bx+c=0\\
$$
for example
$$
x^2 + 2x -15 = 0\\
$$
$$
(x+5)(x-3) = 0
$$
therefore c=
5 \times -3 = -15
$$
$$
and b =
5-3=2
$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `gather*` environment?

Comment: Would normally do but I would like to have a code so I can just enter an equation so that I don't need to type in all the working. I assume i'm just out of my league.

Comment: you should not use `$$` in latex but if you do use it you can not use `\\ ` it is always single line. You have 9 `$$` as you have missed a close, if you used the correct `\[..\]` syntax it would be clear where your expressions start and end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Plain TeX, you can use directly TeX primitive `\noalign`:

```
$$\displaylines{
   ax^2+bx+c=0,\cr
\noalign{\noindent for example:}
   x^2 + 2x -15 = 0 \cr
   (x+5)(x-3) = 0, \cr
\noalign{\noindent therefore}
   c = 5 \times -3 = -15 \quad \hbox{and}\quad b = 5-3 = 2.
}$$

\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose this layout with `\shortintertext`. Hope it befits you.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{gather*}
    ax^2+bx+c=0,\\
    \shortintertext{for example: }
    x^2 + 2x -15 = 0 \\
    (x+5)(x-3) = 0, \\
    \shortintertext{therefore}
     c=5 \times -3 = -15\quad \text{and}\quad b = 5-3=2.
    \end{gather*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]